# How to include the interaction between a covariate and time for a non-proportional hazards model?

Tags: r, cox-regression

How to include the interaction between a covariate and and time for a non-proportional hazards model?

I often find that the proportional hazards assumption for the Cox regressions doesn’t hold.

Take the following data as an example.

```
> head(data2)
   no np_p age_dx1 race1 mr_dx er_1 pr_1 sct_1 surv_mo km_stts1
1  20    1       2     4     1    2    2     4      52        1
2  33    1       3     1     2    1    2     1      11        1
3  67    1       2     4     4    1    1     3      20        1
4  90    1       3     1     3    3    3     2      11        1
5 143    1       2     4     3    1    1     2     123        0
6 180    1       3     1     3    1    1     2       9        1
```

First, I fitted a Cox regression model.

```
> fit2 <- coxph(Surv(surv_mo, km_stts1) ~ np_p + age_dx1 + race1 + mr_dx + er_1 + pr_1 + sct_1, data = data)
```

Second, I assessed the proportional hazards assumption.

```
> check_PH2 <- cox.zph(fit2, transform = "km")
> check_PH2
             rho   chisq        p
np_p     0.00946  0.0748 7.84e-01
age_dx1 -0.00889  0.0640 8.00e-01
race1   -0.03148  0.7827 3.76e-01
mr_dx   -0.03120  0.7607 3.83e-01
er_1    -0.14741 18.5972 1.61e-05
pr_1     0.05906  2.9330 8.68e-02
sct_1    0.17651 23.8030 1.07e-06
GLOBAL        NA 53.2844 3.26e-09
```

So, this means that the hazard function of *er_1* and *sct_1* were nonproportional over time (Right?).

In my opinion, I can include the interaction between these two covariates and time seperately in the model. But I don't know how to perform it using R.

Thank you.

Comment: In R, an interaction is denoted using a `*` symbol. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you for your answer. In other words, I want to know how to deal with the non-proportionality in the Cox regression model when the assumption is not met. I've read many papers including interactions between time and the covariate in this situation.

Comment: @LinCaijin did you find any solution to this isse? It seems to be quite common, but its hard to fine a solution